# Change of variables to solve $\iint_D \frac{y}{x}dxdy$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Given $D: \{4x\leq\ y\leq8x, 2\leq x+4y\leq3\} $. I'm trying to solve: $$\iint_D\frac{y}{x}dxdy$$
So I've tried the substitution: $$u=x+4y\\v=\frac{y}{x}$$
The substitution gives the the new domain $E: \{\ 2\leq u \leq3, 4\leq v \leq8 \}$ and the Jacobian $= \frac{x^2}{u}=\frac{u^2}{u (4v+1)^2}=\frac{u}{(4v+1)^2}$.

So $$\iint_D \frac{y}{x}dxdy=\iint_E \frac{v \ u}{(4v+1)^2}dudv=(\int_{4}^{8} \frac{v}{(4v+1)^2}\ dv) (\int_2^3 u\ du)$$

Needless to say this gives me the wrong solution. I've double checked, but seem to get to the same answer.

Comment: This looks fine to me.  What makes you think it's wrong? The answer is pretty messy.

Comment: The answer/solution in my book gives a different answer.

Comment: There's a solution? Answers may look different without being different, or they may have made a mistake. As I said, what you wrote looks good to me.

Comment: Ok great! I meant the books answer.